# Can a keyboard shortcut to open new instance instead of bringing existing window to front?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the <kbd>F8</kbd> key set as a keyboard shortcut to open a command prompt.  I set it by right clicking on cmd in the start menu, clicking Properties, and setting the Keyboard Shortcut.

My question is whether it's possible to make it so if I have an instance of cmd running, the <kbd>F8</kbd> key will open a new instance, rather than bringing the existing one to the front.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Command Prompt shortcut and, at the end of the "Target:" field, add a " /n" (be sure to include a space before the front slash). This will make that particular shortcut open a new instance of the program.

[image]

Comment: nothing seems to have changed.  the shortcut still just brings the first instance to the front.

Comment: Did you try it without the hotkey? How about other programs/shortcuts?

Comment: ... and you used a front slash, right?

Comment: when I click the option in the start menu, it walways opens a new instance.  it's only when I try to use the hotkey that it brings the previous instance to the front.  and yes I used a front slash

Comment: The hotkey must be linked to the target program, not the shortcut. I don't know of a workaround for this one. You could use a third party program like Launchy or DisplayFusion.

Comment: can confirm adding a `/n` worked for me.